# Flutter: Store bytes in the image

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart

I have a background server with NodeJS + TypeScript.
My server is sending a sendFile which is a png file in response.

I want to store that png file in a flutter image, I've seen other posts but I can't get it to work, hope someone can help me, thanks.

**My dart code:**

```
Future<dynamic> getPapaFaceImage({ String fileName }) async {
    Response response = await dio.get( 
      HANGMAN_GETPAPAFACE+'$fileName',
      options: Options(
        headers: { 'token': Provider.user.token }
      )
    );

    print(response.data);

    // Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList( dataList );
    // return Image.memory( bytes );
    return null;
  }
```

The response I receive on **Dart** is as follows:

[image]

In my **postman** it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What are you going to do with this bytes next?

Comment: I want to return an image that is shown in flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just to display an image from network, there is no need to request bytes manually.

Flutter has an `Image.network` widget for this case out of the box  ([cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image), [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html)).

To specify image url and token in headers, use it like this

```dart
Image.network(
  HANGMAN_GETPAPAFACE + '$fileName',
  headers: { 'token': Provider.user.token },
)
```

Comment: I just learned something new.
I didn't know that Image.network allowed to send headers, thanks!